# How can I restrict Git push through GitHub API?

Tags: git, github

I want to deny users access to "git push" to a repository, but still push via GitHub API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can.
A push is a push - whatever the software is used to do it.

It's like saying "I allow people entering at my home only if they have been driving a Mercedes" (I'm not comparing the gitHub API to a Mercedes, it's just an example ;) )

Try to explain *why* you want that, maybe your need may be expressed differently.